# Quier crear un objeto donde la clave sea el nombre del mecánico y las llaves sean un arreglo con los nombres de los autos que tienen asignados

Tags: javascript, array

Poseo los siguientes arreglos sobre un taller mecanico. En el que quiero ordenar los autos con sus respectivos mecanicos.

```js
     let mecanicos = [
        { id: 1, rut: '132254524', name: 'Pepe'},
        { id: 2, rut: '143618668', name: 'Carlos'},
        { id: 6, Rut: '78684747', name: 'Ricardo' }

    ];

    let autos = [

        { id: 1, name: 'nissan versa' },
        { id: 2, name: 'toyota corola' },
        { id: 3, name: 'chevrolet aveo' }
    ];

    let reparaciones = [

        { idMecanico: 1, idauto: '3', falla: 'motor'},
        { idMecanico: 2, idauto: '1', falla: 'escape'},
        { idMecanico: 2, idauto: '2', falla: 'radiador'},
        { idMecanico: 3, idauto: '1', falla: 'radiador'},
        { idMecanico: 3, idauto: '3', falla: 'radiador'},
        { idMecanico: 3, idauto: '2', falla: 'escape'},
        { idMecanico: 3, idauto: '2', falla: 'llanta'}
       
    ];

    function AutosPorMecanico() {
    
        let names = mecanicos.map((mecanico) => mecanico.name);
                
        const  objeto = {};
        
        names.forEach(function (a) {
                
            objeto [a] = [autos.map((auto) => auto.name).sort()];
            
      });

       return objeto;
    

      }

      console.log(AutosPorMecanico());
```

Estoy creando el objeto con un foreach pero claramente solo estoy asignando los tres autos a cada nombre cuando cada nombre solo deberia mostrar los que realmente tiene asignados... DEsde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es que entendí bien esto es lo que quieres, caso contrario me avisas para cambiar el código.

Los map que tenías creo que no aplican, para este caso es mejor un reduce, donde verificamos si el mecánico tiene auto repetido, luego una función para retornar el auto según su ID (GetAuto)

```js
let mecanicos = [
        { id: 1, rut: '132254524', name: 'Pepe'},
        { id: 2, rut: '143618668', name: 'Carlos'},
        { id: 6, Rut: '78684747', name: 'Ricardo' }

    ];

    let autos = [

        { id: 1, name: 'nissan versa' },
        { id: 2, name: 'toyota corola' },
        { id: 3, name: 'chevrolet aveo' }
    ];

    let reparaciones = [

        { idMecanico: 1, idauto: '3', falla: 'motor'},
        { idMecanico: 2, idauto: '1', falla: 'escape'},
        { idMecanico: 2, idauto: '2', falla: 'radiador'},
        { idMecanico: 3, idauto: '1', falla: 'radiador'},
        { idMecanico: 3, idauto: '3', falla: 'radiador'},
        { idMecanico: 3, idauto: '2', falla: 'escape'},
        { idMecanico: 3, idauto: '2', falla: 'llanta'}
       
    ];

function GetAuto(id){
  for(let a of autos){
    if(a.id==id)
    {
      return a;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
function AutosPorMecanico() {
                
        const  objeto = {};
        
        mecanicos.forEach(function (a) {
              
            objeto[a.name] = reparaciones.reduce((acc,item)=>{
              if(item.idMecanico==a.id){
                acc.push(GetAuto(item.idauto).name);
              }
              return acc;
            },[]);
            
      });

       return objeto;
      }
      console.log(AutosPorMecanico());
```

Comment: !Muchísimas gracias! estoy aprendiendo y tu respuesta me parece optima.  Solo me falta que aparezcan en orden alfabético y no se repitan los autos en caso de que un mecánico tenga el mismo auto por diferente falla. ¿Estaría bien simplemente agregar un .filter() con un .sort() luego de return acc? ¿o hay alguna forma más simple?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con este snippet. El codigo es parecido al anterior pero el resultado esta ordenado por nombre de mecanico y tambien por nombre del auto.

```js
const mecanicos = [
  { id: 1, rut: '132254524', name: 'Pepe'},
  { id: 2, rut: '143618668', name: 'Carlos'},
  { id: 6, Rut: '78684747', name: 'Ricardo' }
];

const autos = [
  { id: 1, name: 'nissan versa' },
  { id: 2, name: 'toyota corola' },
  { id: 3, name: 'chevrolet aveo' }
];

const reparaciones = [
  { idMecanico: 1, idauto: '3', falla: 'motor'},
  { idMecanico: 2, idauto: '2', falla: 'radiador'},
  { idMecanico: 2, idauto: '1', falla: 'escape'},
  { idMecanico: 2, idauto: '1', falla: 'radiador'},
  { idMecanico: 2, idauto: '1', falla: 'llanta'},
  { idMecanico: 3, idauto: '1', falla: 'radiador'},
  { idMecanico: 3, idauto: '3', falla: 'radiador'},
  { idMecanico: 3, idauto: '2', falla: 'escape'},
  { idMecanico: 3, idauto: '2', falla: 'llanta'}
];

const autosPorMecanico = reparaciones.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const mecanicoName = mecanicos.find(
    (curMecanico) => curMecanico.id === cur.idMecanico,
  )?.name || null;
  
  const autoName = autos.find(
    (curAuto) => curAuto.id === +cur.idauto,
  )?.name || null;
  
  const curMecanicoAutos = [...new Set([
    ...acc[mecanicoName] || [],
    autoName,
  ])].sort();
  
  return !mecanicoName || !autoName
    ? acc
    : {
      ...acc,
      [mecanicoName]: curMecanicoAutos,
    };
}, {});

const mecanicoNamesOrdenados = mecanicos.map(
  (mecanico) => mecanico.name,
).sort();

const autosPorMecanicoOrdenados = mecanicoNamesOrdenados.reduce((acc, cur) => ({
  ...acc,
  [cur]: autosPorMecanico[cur] || [],
}), {});

console.log(autosPorMecanicoOrdenados);
```